# Connecting to a Grid Cluster With GridGain

Tags: parallel-processing, grid-computing, gridgain

I know that out of the box that GridGain connects to the other clients through multicast, but is there a way to configure GridGain to accept connections outside of the local network? Also is there a way to enable encryption for the communication as well?

Comment: I'll also suggest you to ask this question on the GridGain forum (http://www.gridgainsystems.com/jiveforums/index.jspa). That's where the committers hang out and respond to questions.

Answer (score 4):

The [Disovery SPI](http://www.gridgainsystems.com:8080/wiki/display/GG15UG/Discovery+SPI) and [Communication SPI](http://www.gridgainsystems.com:8080/wiki/display/GG15UG/Communication+SPI) allows you to plug alternative discovery and communication mechanisms.

For more detail, refer to the comprehensive [API documentation (GridGain 3)](http://blog.griddynamics.com/2008/07/gridgain-on-ec2.html).

This is necessary on Amazon EC2, which doesn't support multicast. Here's an [article](http://blog.griddynamics.com/2008/07/gridgain-on-ec2.html) discussing this setup.

Answer (score 1):

Multicast only works well within a certain network segment (and in some cases this isn't even allowed for security reasons). So if you want to connect nodes to your grid that are outside your local network you have to resort to other transports such as [JMS](http://www.gridgain.com/javadoc30C/org/gridgain/grid/spi/communication/jms/package-summary.html) or [mail](http://www.gridgain.com/javadoc30C/org/gridgain/grid/spi/communication/mail/package-summary.html) (if performance is an issue you might get it away with unicast/static ip's and [JGroups](http://www.gridgain.com/javadoc30C/org/gridgain/grid/spi/communication/jgroups/package-summary.html)).

I think that encryption is possible with both the JMS and mail transport, depending on your message broker and mail setup.